# regeneratorRuntime is not defined after compiling with codeKit using Babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs, codekit

Im trying to uglify a script with code kit that contains references to async functions but I'm having to transpile it with babel in order for it to work. However after checking the console on my site I get smacked with an error 'regeneratorRuntime is not defined' where the arrow functions are supposed to be.

Now I've done a lot of googling and everyone points to do something with npm which I'm not familiar with at all. Is there any settings in codeKit I am missing or require to do in order for it to work.

If not, please could you explain like I'm five how to fix this issue through npm.

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your Codekit Babel configuration seems to be wrong.
Arrow functions are implemented since ES2015 and async functions since ES2017.

You should activate related plugins in case you targeted old browsers.